# Navbar links overllaping @Small tablet landscape (800x600) &Tablet portrait (768x1024)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3 for web mobile app. 
Added my css for navbar drop down menu. Its working fine in most of the devices.

However when verified @ Small tablet landscape (800x600) & Tablet portrait (768x1024), drop down menus are overlapping. 
                     [image]

Please advise.

```
  Also, I have added my code @ http://jsfiddle.net/monicaRegal/y2s97xxk/
```

Thank You
Regards,
Monica Mandal

Comment: When I run your fiddle and adjust the result window to get the navbar to collapse, I don't see any overlapping with your two dropdown items. They push the content down just fine.

Comment: Please check @@ Small tablet landscape (800x600) & @@Tablet portrait (768x1024). You will be able to reproduce the issue

Answer (score 0):

...you can either reduce the size of your elements so that they properly fit in multiple screens, or use another break point for switching to the mobile menu.

edit: elaboration:

I think the part 'reduce the size of your elements' is obvious.

In the bootstrap customizer before you download the files:

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints

...you can customize the resolutions where the breakpoint will take place. Which means you can change the resolution where the navmenu changes to its mobile version.

As a new alternative, I would suggest to alter your design so that it fits your needs.

Second alternative, make the width STATIC instead of fluid down to a resolution where the mobile navigation  will kick in.

Comment: would you please elaborate when you said reduce size of elements.